# How to extract particular fields from lines using shell commands?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, awk, cut

File1:

```
27/07/2014 10.10.03 Breaker1 was closed by Mr. A.Basu Spectrum ui6dms
29/07/2014 04.50.53 Breaker1 was opened by Mr. D.Gupta Spectrum ui6dms and one note added
30/08/2014 03.20.01 EarthSwitch was closed by Mr. K.Saha Spectrum ui1dms
01/09/2014 08.10.39 EarthIsolator was closed by Mr. R.Das Spectrum ui3dms
```

File2:

```
27/07/2014 Breaker1 was closed by Mr. A.Basu ui6dms
29/07/2014 Breaker1 was opened by Mr. D.Gupta ui6dms
30/08/2014 EarthSwitch was closed by Mr. K.Saha ui1dms
01/09/2014 EarthIsolator was closed by Mr. R.Das ui3dms
```

I have more than 100 lines in file1 and I want the output as file2.

Comment: I have tried using cut command but unable to produce the desired result. Then I have tried cat file1 | awk {printf $1,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$10}. @John

Comment: just change `printf` with `print`. Also `cat` is redundant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following command yields the requested output:

```
cut -d ' ' -f 1,3-10 file1
```